# Why does Selenium get stuck on a blank page if I don't manually check?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

Selenium stuck if I don't manually check

My bot runs on server and when I check if it works there isn't any problem. But when I close my server it doesn't work after a while. When I check again I see opened drivers with a blank page, and after I check it starts to continue working in a few seconds.

```
driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options, driver_executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
action = ActionChains(driver)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/login") #it stuck here
```

[When I first check I see this, after a few seconds it continues normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v270w.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "close my server"? Suspend?

Comment: No I mean closing remote server connection on my personal computer.